# How to inherit the implemented methods of subclasses of an abstract grandparent superclass in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop

Suppose that there's an abstract class called MySuperClass (grandparent) that is used as a model for its childs' concrete implementations: MySubClass1 and MySubClass2.
Would there be a way to implement other subclasses (childs) that inherits the implementation of both MySubClass 1 and 2? They have unique methods that i wanted to access from a single instance.

It could work as such:

```
abstract class MySuperClass {
    abstract public function task();
}

class MySubClass1 extends MySuperClass {
    public function task() {
        // implements task for first class
    }

    public function unique1() {
        // implements unique method
    }
}

class MySubClass2 extends MySuperClass {
    public function task() {
        // implements task for second class
    }

    public function unique2() {
        // implements unique method
    }
}

class MyChildClass extends MySubClass1, MySubClass2 {
    // ...
}

$myclass = new MyChildClass;
$myclass->unique1();
```

I have tried dividing them into a single class, but this generates the same problem since i wasn't able to access this task method from other classes because it also has many childs.

Comment: [`traits`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: Note: With trait, the child class can't have access to the `task` method of both `MySubClass1` and `MySubClass2`. The `task` method (or the implementation of it) need to have different name than each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
Programming is not biology - here you can only have one parent.

Also, if you think you need that type of behaviour, then you are incorrectly understanding the point of inheritance. When you write `class B extends A` then what it **means** is that class B is a specialized case of A (or, if you are dealing with abstract classes - more complete case of A).

That's why is is wrong to write `class User extends Table`. Users are not a special subtype of Table (... and I personally would be insulted, if compared to furniture).

---

Since you did not give any details on you real-world problem, it's a bit hard to give any advice, but my general recommendation would be:

> try using more composition instead of inheritance

As in, have that shared logic in a separate class, that you pass in as a dependency in the contructor.